# Authorize net ARB increase subscription amount

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net, credit-card, authorize.net-arb

I am using authorize net ARB subscription api in my application to charge some monthly amount from my users based on the product they select. If a user decides to upgrade his product, the subscription amount will also increase. I want to implement this without having to ask the user for his credit card details again. Can I increase the amount of the ARB subscription? If yes, is there any limit on the increased amount ?(I know that in PayPal, you can increase the subscription amount with an upper limit of 25%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have the user's card information you cannot change the amount in ARB. If not asking the user for their card information again is important to you then you should use the [CIM API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/) which allows you to store credit card information through Authorize.Net and then make payments using that stored information. The only catch is you would need to build your own recurring billing engine as CIM does not handle that.

Comment: You've mentioned that you cannot change the amount without the credit card card info. I guess that holds true only in the case when you are increasing the amount. Decreasing the amount shouldn't require the cc details.